# query only current month using sequelize nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

How to query data only for current month.
i use this query at the moment.

```
  app.get("/api/timesheet_employerId", function (req, res) {
    console.log("I am the employerId", req.user.id)
    db.TimeSheet.findAll({
      include: [
        'employee'
      ],
      order: [['check_in', 'DESC']],
    }).then(function (results) {
      let filtered_result = results.filter(element => element.employee.EmployerId === req.user.id);
      res.json(filtered_result);
    });
  });the
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `seqeulize.literal` in `where` option and compare a first day of month of a certain date with the first day of month of the current date using a condition:

```
(DATE_SUB(check_in,INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(d)-1 DAY)=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(d)-1 DAY))
```